# How to expose a web service which is deployed locally

Tags: java, web-services, web

I am trying to learn webservice building/deployment. I have built a webservice and deployed it on a  oracle weblogic server on my laptop.

i am trying to test the webservice using soapUI from another laptop. i am getting invalid URL error.

can some one point out where i am going wrong

Note the same wsdl works fine if i try to run it from SoapUI on my laptop

Comment: i guess you can use http://wesbos.com/localhost-mobile-device-testing/

Comment: To my knowledge testing the webservice from another laptop would only work if both the laptops are connected via LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops have to be on same network.  If so, each laptop will have its local Ip address ( go to cmd promt if using windows and type ipconfig).

Using this Ip, you can access webservice from second laptop which is hosted on your laptop.

If they are not on same network, it is possible but there are lots of things to be considered. I would suggest that only for production applications, not for testing.